# Round values to fit a negative binomial using GLMMs

Tags: lme4-nlme, glmm, negative-binomial-distribution

I am using a GLMM to model a network metric that ranges from 0 to 100 (contribution to nestedness) and trying to fit a model with four predictors and two random factors (species and site). I have 591 observations. This is the histogram of my variable:

[image: Histogram of my response variable]

I have tried several data distribution families and transformations but the only one that gives me a fairly good qqplot and converges is the negative binomial (rounding the response variable values). Rounding does not change data much, as it ranges from 0 to 100 and thus the loss of information is small.

Is it correct to fit a GLMM (glmer function in R) with a negative binomial distribution using a response variable with non-integer data?

My model looks like this:

```
glmer.nb(round(nestedness)~var1+var2+var3+var4+(1|random1)+(1|random2),
         data=my.data)
```

[Edit 1] I have already tried fitting a Gaussian (and several transformations), Gamma and Beta, distributions, but their Q-Q plots do not look good. Three out of the four variables are factors, the other one is continuous.

Here you can see the Q-Q plot and residuals after fitting the model with a Beta distribution using DHARMa:

[image: Q-Q plot and residuals]

Do you think this may be acceptable?

[Edit 2] Note that the concentration of predicted values at x ~ 0.45 has an ecological explanation due to the data: Each data row represents a species in a site. The concentration represents a same species that appears in different study sites. This species changes widely in its value for the network metric (dependent variable), but it has exactly the same traits (predictor values), so the predicted value is necessarily the same. For this species and a few others there is an ecological explanation for this large variability in the network metric values. This would be the DHARMa plots without the 3 most important species with this problem (out of 160 species):

[image: DHARMa plots without changing species]

Also, interactions or quadratic terms did not improve the fit

[Edit 3] I included one more covariate in the model (the network value for the study site) that is related to the variability in the response variable for the same species (the concentration of points over a same predicted value). Now the model residuals look better:

[image]

Comment: it seems questionable.  I would have suggested a model based on Beta((nestedness+1)/102) (fudge factors to avoid exactly 0/1 valuables). Q-Q plots are the *last* diagnostic you should worry about (details of distribution are generally less important than linearity, homoscedasticity, absence of outliers ...). Can you show the Q-Q plots (and fitted vs residual plots) for the Beta model? (You'll need to use glmmTMB or at least something other than glmer.nb)

Comment: I have just added the plots to the question. Thanks for the fast help!

Comment: As your outcome is bounded and the bounds are evidently attained, at least roughly, only models that respect that seem acceptable. The negative binomial fails absolutely.

Comment: I'm more worried about the overprediction for intermediate levels of fitted values (right-hand DHARMa plot) than the departure from distributional assumptions (Q-Q plot, left-hand). Did your Beta model include all the same terms as your NB model? (1) There's a concentration of values all with the same predicted values at x ~ 0.45; do these represent a special subset of the data, and is it badly fitted? (2) As you inspect the patterns of mis-fit in the residuals (plotting with respect to various predictors), are there places where interactions or quadratic terms might help the fit?

Comment: Thanks for there recommendations, I have added some of that information on the main body of the question